# How to get numerous downloads from google play through Google Developer Api/ Google Analytics API service account

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api-nodejs-client, google-play-developer-api

Good morning everyone, I'm a beginner, after three days trying I still haven't identified how to get the number of downloads of an app on Google Play, can anyone tell me because all the references I found are already out of date. I would like to at least have a valid endpoint for this query. Can be using Google Developer Api or Google analytics API, using service account

I've tried several google Developer api endpoints, and honestly in Analytics I have no idea where to start